# Perl and sub-normal floating-point zeros

Tags: perl, floating-point, ieee-754

Playing with the floating-point format in Perl, I noticed some oddity:
It seems Perl 5.18.2 (on x86_64 Linux at least) does not handle [sub-normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) (like `-0`) correctly (given the IEEE 64-bit binary representation, "2**(-1023 - 52)" should be a sub-normal number different from zero).

```perl-db
main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> $x=2**-1076

  DB<2> x $x
0  0
  DB<3> x $x > 0
0  ''
  DB<4> printf('%g', $x)
0
  DB<5> printf('%e', $x)
0.000000e+00
  DB<6> $x=-2**-1076

  DB<7> x $x
0  0
  DB<8> x $x < 0
0  ''
  DB<9> printf('%g', $x)
-0
  DB<10> printf('%e', $x)
-0.000000e+00
```

Number `2**-1075` still prints as zero, but `2**-1074` prints as `4.94065645841247e-324`.

```perl-db
  DB<20> $x = -2**-1074

  DB<21> x $x < 0
0  1
  DB<22> $x = -2**-1075

  DB<23> x $x < 0
0  ''
  DB<24> printf('%g', $x)
-0
```

Can anybody confirm this, or did a make a thinking error?

Comment: I don't know how strict perl is in this matter, but according to IEEE754, signed zeros should compare equal to each other (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons), therefore `-0.0 < +0.0` must be false.

Comment: Thinking error. The smallest positive subnormal value in IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point is `2**-1074`, not `2**-1075`. Note that an all-zero-bit exponent-field gets interpreted specially - the usual "subtract the bias" rules don't apply. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding for details.

Comment: `POSIX::copysign(0.0, -1)` for generating a negative 0.0, maybe. Not at a computer right now to test.

Answer (score 8):

[*This answer, like the OP, assumes a machine with IEEE doubles for NVs.*]

---

> (given the IEEE 64-bit binary representation, 2**(-1023 - 52)" should be a sub-normal number different from zero).

No.

- Largest subnormal:

  ```perl
  printf "%.1000g\n", unpack "d>", pack "H*", "000FFFFFFFFFFFFF";
  ```

  ```
  2.2250738585072008[...]375e-308    # 100s of digits omitted.
  ```
- Smallest (non-zero) subnormal:

  ```perl
  printf "%.1000g\n", unpack "d>", pack "H*", "0000000000000001";
  ```

  ```
  4.9406564584124654[...]625e-324    # 100s of digits omitted.
  ```

  This is 2<sup>-1074</sup>, not 2<sup>-1075</sup>.
- Smallest "subnormal":

  ```perl
  printf "%.1000g\n", unpack "d>", pack "H*", "0000000000000000";
  ```

  ```
  0
  ```

  A long sequence of zeroes multiplied by a power of two is going to be zero.

---

> It seems Perl [...] does not handle sub-normal numbers

Perl handles subnormals perfectly fine.

```perl
printf "%.1000g\n", 2**(-1074);   # Smallest positive number possible, a subnormal.
```

```
4.9406564584124654[...]625e-324   # 100s of digits omitted.
```

```perl
printf "%.1000g\n", -2**(-1074);  # Smallest negative number possible, a subnormal.
```

```
-4.9406564584124654[...]625e-324  # 100s of digits omitted.
```

---

> It seems Perl [...] does not handle sub-normal numbers (like -0)

While the encoding of zero (positive and negative) is what one would obtain if one encoded the value zero as a subnormal, it seems a bit odd to me to call it a subnormal. But that's just nitpicking.

Perl does support -0.

```perl
printf "%f\n", -0.0;
```

```
-0.000000
```

-0 can also be obtained by underflowing a negative number.

```perl
$_ = -2**(-1074);        # Smallest negative number
$_ /= 2;                 # Underflow
printf "%.1000g\n", $_;
```

```
-0
```

Also,

```perl
printf "%.1000g\n", -2**(-1075);  # Too small
```

```
-0
```

---

Note that -0 is equal to +0, as it should.

```perl
say -0.0 == 0.0 ? "Equal" : "Not equal";
```

```
Equal
```

You can obtain the sign using POSIX's `signbit` (5.22+).

```perl
use POSIX qw( signbit );

say signbit(  0.0 );
say signbit( -0.0 );
```

```
0
1
```

Comment: It seems perl 5.18.2 is handling `printf "%.1000g\n"` differently from your version; e.g. for  `printf "%.1000g\n", unpack "d>", pack "H*", "000FFFFFFFFFFFFF";` I get `2.2250738585072009e-308` (while you seem to get more digits).

Comment: Another confusing thing is that plain `print` seems to ignore some information that `printf` does not ignore. It seems my other mistake was mis-interpreting `unpack "d>", pack "H*", "0008000000000000"` (is 2^-1024, right?).

Comment: Re "*It seems perl 5.18.2 is handling `printf "%.1000g\n"` differently*", Oh wow. I can replicate. On Linux, one gets the longer results starting with 5.28.

Comment: Re "*`"0008000000000000"` (is 2^-1024, right?).*", 2^-1023.